# Angular2+ - Cloning a variable does not prevent from changing it

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that contains data via @Input() "contactInformation".

I would like that the content of contactInformation cannot be changed. Therefore I create a clone so that there is no reference.

```
export class ContactInformationComponent implements OnIni {
  @Input() contactInformation: ContactInformationModel;

  public businessArray = [];

  constructor(){
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.businessArray = [...this.contactInformation.business];
  }
```

If I change the data via an input field, it will also be changed to contactInformation.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of businessArray; let i=index">
  <td>
   <div *ngIf="!isEditingInt"
        id="{{configParams[1].key}}">{{getLabeTOUCH_POINT_OPTIONS)}}</div>
   <div *ngIf="isEditingInt">
     <div class="d-inline-block">
        <input class="form-control"
         name="contact_name_{{i}}"
         [required]="configParams[2].required"
         [(ngModel)]="item.contactName">
     </div>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
...
```

I would have expected that only the array would be adjusted because there is no more reference to contactInformation.

Where do I make the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is cloned, the objects in your array are not. If it's a shallow object, you can do the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.businessArray = [...this.contactInformation.business].map((data) => ({ ...data }));
}
```

There are also a lot of libraries which can help you with this

Comment: OK, thats working on arrays with key value [ { "key1": "value 1", "key2": "value 2" }, { "key1": "an other value 1", "key2": "an other value 2" } ] - And on lists like [ "1", "2" ]? I think I need to use .map((data) => data); (x) => x thats called identity, right? so, map(identity) clones a list. like [ "1", "2" ].
That is working also so far. but on edit the value in the field, the content of the cloned array is not changing.

Comment: The problem is with using an array of primitive values  [ "1", "2" ] in ngFor.
I think I have to change to an array of objects .

Comment: I change now the array of primitives to array of objects like : .map((data) => ({data})); and all works fine now.

Comment: and just to complete the part, to convert back from array of objects to list: .map((data) =>(
      data.data
    ));